# Issue passing array as argument [to InvokeArg()] in php - var_dump are the same but only one works?

Tags: php, arrays

Backstory: Creating function to handle mysqli and binding data. All code is in the scope of a single function. Using ReflectionClass to programmatically invoke mysqli_stmt_bind_param function (as number of arguments vary).

Problem: I am having an issue passing an array I built up programmatically ($refArr). When I compare the var_dump of this array (with a sample array I created directly), the two arrays are identical. The invokeArg() method runs with the sample array ($refArr_sample) but not with $refArr.

Here is the output for the code shown below:

> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "si" [1]=> string(5) "user1" [2]=> int(0) } - output of refArr
>
> array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "si" [1]=> string(5) "user1" [2]=> int(0) } - output of refArr_sample

```
$refArr_sample = array("si", "user1", 0);

// var_dump are equal in type and length
var_dump($refArr);
var_dump($refArr_sample);

$ref    = new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt');
$method = $ref->getMethod("bind_param");

$method->invokeArgs($res,$refArr); // Doesn't Work ?????????
//$method->invokeArgs($res,$refArr_sample); // Works ?????????

$res->execute();
```

I am unsure how to fix the problem (as I've no clue what the problem is). I don't think this is an issue with references. Once the var_dump is the same I thought it wouldn't have mattered. I also did a === comparison between the two arrays which came back true. At this point I am lost as to why it isn't working.

I can link the complete code (self contained function) if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should note that the values in the passed array **must** be references (as of PHP 5.3), whereas your `$refArr` is built dynamically.

```
...
//assign references
foreach ($refArr as $key => $value) {
   $refArr[$key] =& $refArr[$key];
}

$method->invokeArgs($res,$refArr);

...
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still a bit confused but this is going along way towards helping with that confusion!

Comment: Whole notes/comments on [`mysqli::bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) are useful and must-see to help you minified such confusion.